# Consulta modelo base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos, modelorelacional

Escribo para realizar una consulta u orientación sobre un MER referente a un sistema de inventario.

Tengo dos entidades :

```
Equipo ------------------- Usuario
```

Según mis requerimientos necesito generar una relación muchos a muchos, por lo cual se me genera una entidad nueva a la cual denomino "Asignación"

```
Asignación

- ID Asignación PK

- ID Equipo FK

- ID Usuario FK
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente, puedo asignar nuevamente otra FK de la entidad Usuario a la entidad Asignación? Necesito Incorporar ademas del usuario el técnico responsable de esa asignación y no quiero crear una entidad nueva para técnico ya que los atributos son similares a los que tiene la entidad usuario.

Gracias,

Comment: Creo que tu entidad `Usuario` se deberia llamar `Persona` y tener un atributo `tipo` o `rol` el cual tendria el valor de usuario o tecnico o administrador o lo que sea.  Usando ese formato puedes agregar la llave foranea que deseas.

Comment: Diría que *depende*. Lo que dice @alanfcm de dar **nombres descriptivos** a tus entidades es de suma importancia, para ti y para otros. Aquí yo interpreto que en tu entidad `Equipo` habrá **varios usuarios** reunidos bajo un interés común. No sé si sea así, pero eso es lo que hace pensar. Entonces, la pregunta es si el técnico responsable ¿lo es de un equipo de usuarios? Si así fuera, **habría redundancia de datos** con respecto al id del técnico responsable y por tanto, el técnico responsable debería ser trasladado a la entidad `Equipo`. Repito, si es como hace imaginar el **nombre** `Equipo`

Comment: Yo lo entendi como que `Equipo` se refiere a hardware, y `Tecnico` se refiere al que repara el equipo, por eso `Usuario` seria el usuario del equipo

Comment: @alanfcm aunque así fuera, me parece que debe haber algo que agrupe a varios equipos y ese *algo* puede ser incluso el técnico bajo cuya responsabilidad están esos equipos. Otra cosa en la que hay que pensar cuando diseñas un modelo de datos es en las posibles consultas: supongamos que te piden un catálogo de equipos bajo la responsabilidad del técnico `X` ... si tienes el dato mezclado en la tabla `asignacion` va a ser mucho más difícil y de todos modos seguirás teniendo redundancia de datos. En fin, creo que le faltan detalles importantes a la pregunta.

Comment: Primero agradecer sus comentarios. La situación es como la señala @alanfcm entre equipo y usuario se origina una relación llamando asignación luego a Esa asignación se le realizarán muchos soportes (tabla soportes) que serán las mantenciones y ahi es donde quiero asignar una fk de la entidad usuario...se me olvidó mencionar que en la entidad usuario existe una fk de la entidad tipo_usuario (roles)...me quedan dudas ya que un usuario puedes ser un responsable del equipo o un tecnico encargado del soporte...será necesario crear la entidad tecnico?

Comment: Equipo=hardware

Comment: Usuario=A quien se le asigna el equipo

Comment: Soporte = Mantenciones realizadas a ese equipo